# Why is the Performance Explorer re-opened on start-up of VS 2013 Professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have an annoying problem with Visual Studio 2013 Professional.
I tried doing some profiling, and ever since then, my Solution start-up is screwed up.
No matter how I save my Solution, the Performance Explorer is re-opened.
Also, all the projects in the Solution Explorer has everything expanded.

Does anyone know how to delete the Start-up cache on VS 2013?
Articles on how to do this for earlier versions of VS no longer apply.

Charles